# Android-Spinners- Force Close Error

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, spinner, forceclose

---- I did move the spinner and textview variables under setcontentview but then spinners are not known publicly so i could use them in void onitemselected  what should i do ???

Ok So I want to use spinners to get my values from them and compare it with the randomly generated ones and if they are correct shows them in textview as green if not as red
and I only did this IF statement for one spinner just to test it but it force closes.

MainPage.java

```
package com.example.decrypter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainPage extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    double random1;
    int check1,check2,check3,check4,check5;

    EditText textbox;
    int guess;
    String s;
    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner01);
    Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner02);
    Spinner spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner03);
    Spinner spinner4 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner04);
    Spinner spinner5 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner05);
    TextView display1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtdisplay1);
    TextView display2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtdisplay2);
    TextView display3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtdisplay3);
    TextView display4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtdisplay4);
    TextView display5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtdisplay5);

    Integer[] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    Button btnrandom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnrandom);
    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ArrayAdapter <Integer> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter <Integer>(this,       android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, numbers);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);
        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter1);
        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spinner3.setAdapter(adapter1);
        spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spinner4.setAdapter(adapter1);
        spinner4.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spinner5.setAdapter(adapter1);
        spinner5.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        btnrandom.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() 
        { 

           public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            random1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10); 
            //display.setText("random:" + random1);     
            /*check1 = Integer.parseInt(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString())     ; 
            */
        }
       });

        btn1.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() 
        { 

           public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(check1==random1){
                display1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                display1.setText(s);
            }
            else{
                display1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                display1.setText(s);
            }   
        }
       });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_page, menu);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        check1 = Integer.parseInt(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString());
        check2 = Integer.parseInt(spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString()) ;
        check3 = Integer.parseInt(spinner3.getSelectedItem().toString()) ;
        check4 = Integer.parseInt(spinner4.getSelectedItem().toString()) ;
        check5 = Integer.parseInt(spinner5.getSelectedItem().toString()) ;

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

AndroidManifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.decrypter"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainPage"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main_page" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write below code into onCreate() method after this code line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);`, it will solve your problem.

```
Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner01);
Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner02);
Spinner spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner03);
Spinner spinner4 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner04);
Spinner spinner5 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner05);

TextView display1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtdisplay1);
TextView display2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtdisplay2);
TextView display3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtdisplay3);
TextView display4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtdisplay4);
TextView display5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtdisplay5);

Button btnrandom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnrandom);
Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
```

Comment: if i move the spinners then i cant use them in Public void onitemselected as it wont be recognized even if i put final before it what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

FYI, you can find Views without setting Layout to your activity class. So write those `findViewsById()` after `setContentView()`.

For example:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);     //set layout 

     Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner01);
     Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner02);
     .....
     .....
     .....
}
```

one more thing, if you want to access these all views at whole class, declare Class level for those.

Comment: if i move the spinners then i cant use them in Public void onitemselected as it wont be recognized even if i put final before it what should i do ?